# where col1 from tab1 and col1 from tab2 in select from tab3

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wanna gets some records from table A and table B, they don't have any common records but my select is depends on from table C which have keys to A and B, for example:
I have 3 tables: A, B and C, something like that:

```
      A
+----+-------+
| ID | NAME  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | nameA |
+----+-------+


     B
+----+-------+
| ID | NAME  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | nameB |
+----+-------+



        C
+-----+-----+-------+
| IDA | IDB | NAMEC |
+-----+-----+-------+
|   1 |   1 | nameC |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

and i wanna get sth like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| NameA | NameB |
+-------+-------+
| nameA | nameB |
+-------+-------+
```

so I am trying with:

```
 select a.name, b.name
    from tableA a, tableB b
    join (select idA, idB
    from   tableC where nameC='nameC') tmp
    on tmp.idA=a.id and tmp.idB=b.id
```

but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just two joins and filtering:

```
select a.name as nameA, b.name as nameB
from tableC c join
     tableA a
     on c.idA = a.id join
     tableB b
     on c.idB = b.id
where c.nameC = 'nameC';
```

Your code does not work because you are mixing archaic join syntax (commas) with proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas.  Always use `JOIN`.

The reason your code does not work is because of the scoping rules around commas.  The `ON` clause does not recognize the first table reference.

Comment: i am dumb, its working, i should use inner join cause sql oracle , haha, thanks m8